# States for input field when typing

Tags: css

Is there some sort of state(like `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`) for when typing in an input field only using CSS or does this have to be done in another way like JavaScript?

What I want to achieve is to only display a character counter when someone is typing.

Comment: why css and not in js as it can be possible only by js.

Comment: It will be done in JS but I was more curious if there was a way because that would speed my process up.

Comment: I think css will work after DOM loaded, Until you consider JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no state in css when typing in an input field.

Please see the link for more info about **pseudo classes**
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

> The state for input when typing is possible in javascript.

Please see the code below.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert("Someone is typing");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo">
```

> You can see more info about onkeypress in this link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to implement js then :)

Comment: I’m happy to help.